# GWT: how do I scroll to the bottom of the page?

Tags: java, gwt, scrollbar

On my page I have a panel which is hidden by default. I can show it via `myPanel.setVisible(true)` when necessary. After this the height of the window is increased and the window scrollbar appears.

The problem is that the window is not scrolled to the bottom automatically, which is a desired behaviour. How can I fix it? I just want to scroll my page to the bottom.

I know `Window.scrollTo (LEFT, TOP)` can help me. But the problem is that I dont know how can I calculate the height of the page relative to the top - the second parameter I need to provide to this method. I really tried numerous ways:

```
Window.getClientHeight();
Document.get().getScrollHeight();
Document.get().getBody().getOffsetHeight();
Document.get().getBody().getAbsoluteBottom();
```

First two of them do not change their value after the hidden panel becomes visible. The second pair gives me 0 and 8 (???) values.

So how can I solve my issue?

ps
If the situation is a bit different and I have a div with a scrollbars, not the window scrollbars, is it possible to scroll it to the bottom programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it simple Panel or some subclass of it.

In any case, try first with:

```
int top = myPanel.getAbsoluteTop();
```

and then scroll to some value aggregated with top.

From API:

***public int getAbsoluteTop()***

Gets the object's absolute top position in pixels, as measured from the browser window's client area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setVerticalScrollPostion](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#setVerticalScrollPosition%28int%29) API and set the position of the scroll

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling down the document, you should use the scrollTo method in Window object, i.e.:

```
Window.scrollTo(0, Window.getScrollTop() + Window.getClientHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to know the size of the page to scroll to it's bottom. Just use

`Window.scrollTo(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

At least this always worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want , you can create a widget handle with an id.
For example : `widget.getElement().setId("scrollPanel");`

Then you can scroll the view on the widget with `Document.get().getElementById("scrollPanelFooter").scrollIntoView();`
It's simpler!

Comment: Excuse me, I correct myself : widget.getElement().setId("scrollHandle"); Document.get().getElementById("scrollHandle").scrollIntoView(); scrollHandle is the name of widget id.

Comment: you can edit your own post ... look for "edit" at your post and click on it.